# UDP client timing issue in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, udp

I have created a UDP client to receive information form a host in C#. 
I am using the Receive() method in a while loop to get the data from the server. But I am having a bit of a problem with its timing.

The rate at which data packets are sent from the server is around 10ms and whenever the packet count reached 32 (=320 ms), I rise a SubFrameReady event. 
The problem is that this event is raised every 1 ms!! Dos the UDP receive the same packet over and over again because it is in a while loop?
Here is the code:

```
private void threadFunction()
    {
        byte[] rcvBuff;
        int start = XDef.HEADER_LENGTH;
        int end = _imgWidth * _bytesPerPixel + XDef.HEADER_LENGTH;

        startFrameData();
        while (true)
        {
            rcvBuff = imgListener.Receive(ref localEp);
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                imgHeader[i] = rcvBuff[i];
            }
            for (int i = start; i < end; i += 2)
            {
                _rawLineData[byteCounter] = rcvBuff[i] + rcvBuff[i + 1] * 256;
                _lineData[byteCounter] = (byte)(_rawLineData[byteCounter] * 255 / 65535);
                byteCounter++;
            }
            lineCounter++;
            // Thread.Sleep(5);
            if (lineCounter % _subFrameHeight == 0)
            {
                byteCounter = 0;
                if (SubFrameReady != null)
                    SubFrameReady.Invoke(this, null);
                if (lineCounter % _imgHeight == 0)
                {
                    if (FrameReady != null)
                        FrameReady.Invoke(this, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"The problem is that this event is raised every 1 ms!! Dos the UDP receive the same packet over and over again because it is in a while loop?"_ - The `Thread.Sleep(5)` alone should be enough for the event to be triggered less than once a millisecond. Maybe check `sender` for who is raising the event.

Comment: It´s not quite evident what you are trrying to achieve but: UDP does not guarantee delivery or uniqueness or right order. If you want to receive a "stream" of structured data it´s up to you to make sure that all data is there (for example by numbering datagrams). Relying on timing is a bad idea (you might even miss datagrams).

Comment: Oh, sorry! 
I added the Thread.sleep() later. It should not be there.

Comment: @C. Gonzalez: That is actually a very good point. The server actually does send the packet IDs. Why did I not think of that.
Thanks a lot. I will try it and see how it goes.

Comment: Well I tried many things, no luck!
The server send packets every 10 milliseconds (and the Wireshark confirms this), how is it that I get packets in less than 1ms on C# (both async and sync methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I got the answer. 
The timing is perfectly fine. The problem was that I was debugging the application while trying to analyze the time and I had set breakpoints. 
I think the buffer in UDP Client class saves the coming data when the app is paused and then loads the Receive() method with that data as soon as it can which was the reason why I was getting the 1ms time frame.

It was very tricky!

Comment: And I need to add something to this.
You better set the ReceiveBufferSize to 0 when working with time sensitive applications, otherwise the timing is not right for a couple of packets at the beginning of the transfer. 
The UDPClient will try to get all the data which will shrink the time scale at the beginning, but when you set the ReceiveBufferSize  to 0, you will loose some of the packets when transfer starts, but everything is fine after that.